# Replace Certain character with regex android

Tags: java, android, regex

I trying to replace eg: `Jack's House` to maybe a random String from a listeg:{"Jason" ,"Chris", ....} `Jason's House` using regex expression,Im only want to replace The "Jack" to a random String from a List`pLines`,So this is what I thought of my regex ,The [A-Za-z] is suppose to allow a random character, \n|' is to allow white space or the speical char " ' " and [S|s] is to allow either s or Uppercase s and "House|house" is to allow House or house,lastly "^ $" is startline and endline   Implementation:

```
 public String generateRandomPlaces(String PlaceName){
        String HouseRegex = "(^[A-Za-z]+\n|\n|'+[Ss]+House|house$)";
        Pattern NameRegex = Pattern.compile(HouseRegex);
        Matcher matcher = NameRegex.matcher(PlaceName);
        Pname pname = new Pname(this);
        pLines = pname.readStr(aPath);
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(String s : pLines)
        if(PlaceName.matches(HouseRegex)){
           return PlaceName.replaceAll(s , pLines.get(rand.nextInt(pLines.size())));

        }



        return PlaceName.replace("([A-Za-z])" , pLines.get(rand.nextInt(pLines.size())));
    }
```

Am I doing it wrong with regular expression or do need to add something

Comment: Ya, I change that one alr, what abt the regex, is that wrong??

Comment: is like Jack's House to "random from a Person Name list" Jason's House, just wanna replace the Jack to other name

Comment: So may be: `str.replaceFirst("^.*?([sS]+House)$", pLines.get(rand.nextInt(pLines.size()));`

Comment: yes that's right

Comment: It works one way or another, but instead, it replaces the whole String from the list

Answer (score 0):

Your regex has some small mistake, change it to:

```
  String HouseRegex = "(^[A-Za-z]+\n|\n|'+[Ss]+House|House$)";
```

**h**ouse -> **H**ouse

You could check and test your regex [here](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: but it is intended, I want it to be able to recognise both House and house

Comment: In that case that regex doesn't work with House, it fails.